# Bad question or example of Stack Overflow not being welcoming?

Tags: discussion

Today I came across the following question in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) (not linking to avoid meta effect):

> ## in Python, How I represent like this?
>
> I make this:
>
> ```python
> print('number id {0:1.3}.{0:1.3}.{0:1.3}-{0:1.3}'.format("12345678910"))
> ```
>
> result : `number id 123.123.123-123`
>
> how I make correct? like this:
>
> ```python
> number id 123.456.789-10
> ```

---

It was posted by a new user (11 days) and was originally unformatted. This question received 7 downvotes (no upvotes) within ~10 minutes of posting. There were also two basically RTFM comments.

> just read basic string formatting first
>
> ---
>
> You told the thing to print the first three characters several times. What do you expect to happen?

I read a lot of python questions, and in my opinion this is not a terrible question. It's not great (I didn't upvote it), but OP described the problem clearly and showed their attempt.

I am wondering what the community thinks:

Is this an unsalvageable, bad question? Does it epitomize the gist of [Stack Overflow isn't very welcoming](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?cb=1)?

---

**EDIT**

I realize now that I wasn't clear enough on my intent on this post. It turned into a referendum on one specific post, but my goal was to spark a discussion about the reaction to the post (not the post itself). I also attempted to give my opinion of the post, without passing judgement on the reaction- though I believe it was interpreted as criticizing the down-voters and commenters (not my intention).

I'm leaving the original content untouched so that the existing comments/answers don't lose context, but if I had to rewrite this question I would have said something like:

*It was posted by a new user who is almost surely not a native English speaker. The question received 7 downvotes (no upvotes) within ~10 minutes of its posting. There were two comments, which can be interpreted as basically saying RTFM. The OP responded to the first saying that they had in fact read the manual, but still didn't understand how to achieve their desired result.*

*I read a lot of python questions and this didn't seem like a 7 downvote question. For example, compare it to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50005537/i-want-to-know-how-do-json-file-work-in-python-please-explain-about-json-file#comment87028077_50005537) which only has 8 DVs- among the worst questions I've seen asked here. Furthermore, this question had only 1 CV.*

*I would have normally considered skipping this question but decided to answer after seeing the strong negative reaction combined with having recently read Jay Hanlon's blog post. Also, the OP showed their attempt and it was clear (to me) that it was an easy problem to solve.*

*I think that the language barrier was a major reason for the poor reception here. If the poster was a native English speaker, it's possible (not definite) that they would have posed it in a more acceptable manner. My experience (anecdotal) is that most similar difficulty (subjective) questions with cut-and-pastable code are well received if they are well written (without typos, good grammar, etc).*[<sup>1</sup>](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366710/bad-question-or-example-of-stack-overflow-not-being-welcoming#comment579334_366711)

*I am interested in hearing the community's thoughts on this situation? Is this type of question unsalvageable, worthy of being downvoted into oblivion? Is there a consensus on the appropriate action? I understand that there is a concern that answering LQQ can lead to more LQQ but everyone has to find the right balance for themselves. I have found that you can try to show people the right way. Many people take the direction and improve. Those that do not typically do not persist for long as people can see their histories and choose to move on/DV.*[<sup>2</sup>](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366710/bad-question-or-example-of-stack-overflow-not-being-welcoming#comment579316_366710)

Comment: Doesn't really answer your question, but a better edit would have been a great first step to helping this individual out.  I know you didn't make the original edit, but fixing the code formatting was not enough.  The grammar is not good.  And the title does nothing to actually describe the problem.  Fixing both could have helped make the question more presentable.

Comment: Why does everyone think "being welcoming" has to equate to "upvoting low quality questions instead of downvoting them"?  Someone downvoting a question that they don't think is a good question is not acting inappropriately.  Being welcoming means that the people that commented were all polite and professional in telling the OP what they needed to be researching before asking their question instead of saying "RTFM".

Comment: It is a bad question because it does not explain why the correct output is correct. What's to stop you from doing `print('123.456.789-10')`. What if it has more digits? What if it has less? When you answer these questions you almost always get a comment saying "but I have this extra requirement". Is this unsalvageable? Yes, unless the OP makes it clearer. That doesn't make SO welcoming though. It's certainly not but I agree that it is more of a structural issue than a community issue.

Comment: @ayhan: "*It is a bad question because it does not explain why the correct output is correct.*" I disagree. They don't need to say why that is the correct output. They want a certain output; they *expected* the program to provide that output, but it doesn't. There's no need to investigate further. Clearly, the OP doesn't understand how Python formatting works.

Comment: @NicolBolas I honestly couldn't figure out the logic there. If you say it is clear from context then of course someone might edit it and it would become salvageable.

Comment: @Servy I didn't say being welcoming means upvoting LQQ. I am wondering if, rather than downvoting a new user, it would be more productive to the community in general by trying to guide them to ask better questions. (Not that I am claiming that I did this). I think the downvotes and comments can be demoralizing. Without an explanation, you may very well drive this person away.

Comment: @ayhan I thought it was clear because of the code snippet they provided.

Comment: @pault: More productive for whom? For us as users of the platform? No. More productive for people who aren't willing to invest time in asking a good question? Sure. But which of these groups matter *more*?

Comment: "*rather than downvoting a new user*" so any questions by new users should be immune to downvote, or... require commenting on downvote (this again?)?

Comment: To almost any answerer in [python], this will take ~30 seconds to edit into shape. The requirement is clear because there's a *desired output* -> gold dust as far as I'm concerned when it comes to these questions. My qualm is 7 people downvoted without editting it into shape.

Comment: @AndrewT. certainly not, but maybe they should get a little more leeway? I am not stating these as my opinions, just asking what others think.

Comment: @pault: "*certainly not, but maybe they should get a little more leeway?*" Why? Why couldn't they show *us* some leeway by asking a good question the first time around?

Comment: @NicolBolas more productive to everyone in the long run (perhaps idealistic). Helping new users ask better questions in the future is a win for everyone. If someone doesn't want to participate in that, then they can move on.

Comment: @pault: I don't see how editing someone's question helps them to ask better questions. It trains them to expect us to fix their questions for them.

Comment: @NicolBolas not editing it, but explaining to them where they went wrong, pointing them to resources like [tour] and [ask], etc.

Comment: @NicolBolas Or maybe it shows them how they should have asked their question? Or how they should have used markdown to format it? These seem quite possible to me.

Comment: @pault: That would take *longer* than editing. And we have dozens and dozens of pages telling people how to ask. How is this a more productive use of the time of an expert than to go and answer the question of someone who took the time to ask well?

Comment: @pault There aren't enough people on SO willing and able to personally tutor every single person asking a bad question in how to ask a good question.  Additionally, a huge percentage of the people asking bad questions have no interest in being tutored in how to ask a good question.  You're more than welcome to spend as much of your time as you want trying to help people ask better questions.  That's great.  What's not good is demanding that everyone else do so for every bad question that they see, because that's just not a possibility.

Comment: @NicolBolas and if you do edit you get scolded anyway for removing the *Hello* and *Thanks*

Comment: @pault People are *already* directed to the tour, and the how to ask pages.  The people asking bad questions have already made an explicit decision to ignore such information when the site explicitly told them that they were expected to read through them before asking their question.  The people that asked anyway are the people that already know about those pages and weren't interested.

Comment: Also worth noting that you did none of said things to help the OP improve their question in that example.  You just posted your best guess of an answer to an unclear and poorly researched question, instead of helping the OP clarify their question and learn how to do their research properly, the way the other commentors of the question did.  In other words the people your criticizing are the ones who are doing the things that you claim you want to see, while you aren't doing any of the things you claim you want to see.

Comment: 'There were also two basically RTFM comments' well, it the comment had been, literally, 'RTFM', then SO would have probably rejected it as rude.  So, commenter posts 'just read basic string formatting first', which is then describled as 'basically RTFM'.  So, what exactly is the SO-suggested RTFM?  Should we use longer words, more typing, or are we supposed to read the documentation, find the right section, precis it and copy in the relevant bits, (cos that's never going to happen).

Comment: 'My qualm is 7 people downvoted without editing it into shape' what if I edit it 'into shape' and accidentally introduce a new bug?  Tomorrow, the OP is blaming me for 4 hours of lost work.  No thanks.

Comment: 'Helping new users ask better questions in the future is a win for everyone' even if that happened, (and there is no lock that the OP would even ask another question, never mind in any better manner), it's not a win for everyone because any time spent on 'fixing' bad questions is less time spent on good questions.  Time and effort is free when someone else is doing the work:(

Comment: @NicolBolas your point is valid- but I'm not advocating that everyone do this. Just pointing out an alternative. If an expert didn't think a question was worth their time, then they can skip it - no harm there. My question is really trying to understand if this is an example of what the blog post was describing. I'm not advocating either position here- I'm just trying to see what the community thinks in these cases.

Comment: @Servy the question was clear to me so I answered it. I am not asking (or demanding) anyone to personally invest more time than they want. Maybe that's what the blog post is doing, but I am certainly not telling anyone else what to do.

Comment: @Makoto this question isn't really about the specific question (although I did tag it specific-question) so I'm not sure the dupe applies (there was only one VTC). It's more about if this situation is representative of the content outlined in the recent blog post.

Comment: @pault You maybe misread others' comments. The point is that your editing and answering to a poor question is *harmful* to the site. Only when those poor-question-askers find their question never gets response/answer, will they leave the site or start learning how to use the site, both of which are the result we want. Editing and answering those question is encouraging them to come back again with more poor questions.

Comment: I would counter-argue that Python has been a bit more "special" in the past in that it kind of sees these kinds of questions come through all the time and a *lot* of denizens think that these kinds of questions are okay to be on the site.  In my mind it makes no sense to think about being welcoming if we can't determine if this kind of question even belongs here in the first place.

Comment: @liliscent one approach is to ignore these people and hope they never come back or learn learn how to use the site on their own. Another approach is to (optionally) try to help people become better contributors. It seems like SO prefers the latter. Everyone has to find the right balance for themselves, but I have found that you can try to show people the right way. Many people take the direction and improve. Those that do not typically do not persist for long as people can see their histories and choose to move on/DV.

Comment: @Makoto *In my mind it makes no sense to think about being welcoming if we can't determine if this kind of question even belongs here in the first place.* - excellent point. FWIW I think this happens in python because it's popular and relatively easy to learn. Maybe I should have asked *"Does this question belong?"*

Comment: @Makoto: "*In my mind it makes no sense to think about being welcoming if we can't determine if this kind of question even belongs here in the first place.*" The question being asked here would be just as valid if it were PHP or JavaScript or whatever. It would have met with the same cascade of downvotes and probably snarky comments.

Comment: The intolerance on stackoverflow AND stackexchange stinks. As a retired software and electronics engineer at it since the days of APPLE IIE and ATARI, I think its fair to say that when I have a question, it is likely that others will have the same one. Unfortunately, some questions are complicated by "ifs" and "buts" and are difficult to explain in a short sentence. So after enough unexplained down-votes to get me a 6 month ban, I won't often be asking here anymore. The sad things is when I find a good answer to someone eases question, where the OP also received multiple down votes.   ,

Answer (score 50):

You asked one question, but bound to it is a number of other questions.

1. Is this a question deserving of downvotes?

   I'm not a Python programmer, but I would say "sure". The question as it originally stood was poorly formatted. Even after the formatting issues were fixed, there were many other problems with it, from the bad title to the !English.

   Calling this question "clear" does a disservice to people who take the time to ask well-formed questions.
2. Is this question unsalvageable?

   No. It can be made into a decent question. Its simplicity (I assume; I'm not a Python programmer) means that it's unlikely to become a *good* question, but it can be made into something not-terrible.
3. Is it OK to downvote salvageable questions?

   Absolutely. You vote based on the content as it currently stands, not as it *might* be. If content could be made better, it's OK for you to make it better. It's also OK for you to downvote and move on.

Comment: Would you care to opine on the comments to that question? Or are they condoned because the question is downvotable?

Comment: @AndrewT.: OK, my opinion on the comments is what it has always been: garbage in, garbage out. Ask a bad question, it's not unreasonable to expect less-than-stellar responses from people who've had to sift through 50 bad questions *just today*.

Comment: A piece of garbage for a piece of garbage makes the whole network a little more garbage.

Comment: A bad question should never be an excuse for snarky comments. I agree with the content, but not with the tone of the comments on this question. It would have taken the same amount of time to write them more positive.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: I'm not saying it's a good thing; I'm saying it's the *expected* thing. If you allow lots of garbage into your system, you're going to create more garbage. If you work to stop bad questions from showing up at all, you'll get a lot fewer of these comments, *even* on other bad questions that slip through.

Comment: I think that the language barrier was a major reason for the poor reception here. If the poster was a native English speaker, it's possible (not definite) that they would have posed it in a more acceptable manner. My experience (anecdotal) is that most similar difficulty (subjective) questions with cut-and-pastable code are well received if they are well written (without typos, good grammar, etc).

Answer (score 31):

One of the greatest issues with the internet is the implied tone of phrases, where the reader decides if a phrase is rude/unwelcoming or not.

The comment that most called my attention was:

> You told the thing to print the first three characters several times. What do you expect to happen?

I read this and re-read the question, because I didn't get why this was being quoted. I didn't see it as rude. So I decided to try something. I re-read the comment twice, once in the voice of a jerk in a tech class in high school who was always putting people down, and once in the voice of my current team lead at work who was also my trainer originally. Both people who might make this comment. Here are the results of what the implied tone said instead of the actual words.

Jerk's voice: You don't have any idea what you're doing, do you? You wrote code to print out the first three characters several times. Why do you think the computer will do something you don't understand in the first place?

Team Lead's voice: See here? Those lines will make it print out the first three characters several times. What do you expect the code to do instead?

---

The difference between these is that one is reading the original comment as someone trying to be condescending, the other is someone trying to understand the circumstance  so that they have enough information to help you (understand what you expect to help you get there).

I do not believe that the commenter is on Stack Overflow because they get their kicks making fun of bad code. In my experience, the people here really do want to help, and they desire to help people construct good productive questions and answers. But this is the internet, and you can't hear anyone's voice or tone as they speak. So if a person reads a comment *expecting* the writer to be condescending, then that's how they will hear it, thus leading to a feeling of the site being unwelcoming. But if the person reads a comment and imagines the voice and tone of someone they trust, someone who gives constructive feedback, then they will be able to receive the comment in a welcoming way.

Of course there will always be a few bad apples, people who are explicitly rude. But in my experience, they don't stay around the site that long. The people I see commenting and answering and flagging are good people wanting to help the site and help the users. Though if someone tries to be offended by whatever they read, or are looking at SO community members as elitists who look down on the new users, or anything else that creates a rude, condescending or otherwise unwelcoming tone, then they will be offended and find what they expect to see regardless of how welcoming the Stack Overflow users they come into contact with try to be.

So bad question or example of Stack Overflow not being welcoming? To my eyes, I'd say Stack Overflow was plenty welcoming, so it was the question that needed some work.

Comment: I think this is a huge stretch. There are thousands of brusque comments like that on the site; in my opinion they are a sign of frustration on the part of the reviewer. `What did you expect to happen` is literally included in the question (`how I make correct? like this`). If the commentor's intentions were true, they could have answered to with an explanation on why the observed behavior occurred. As it stands it is the 'jerk' answer, not the 'team lead'.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst This is exactly my point. You expect the reviewers to be frustrated, and so you hear it that way. And it feels clear as day to you because that is how you are reading it, and it's difficult for you to see it any other way. And maybe there are some frustrated reviewers (though I find it hard to understand why a person would spend their free time doing something they don't enjoy like reviewing posts if it irritates them so much) who do comment rudely, like the bad apples I mentioned. But this comment in particular is only offensive if you decide it to be offensive.

Comment: We can say that about any comment - it's only offensive if you let it be offensive. As I noted, for this to be true the commentor has to misread the question (which explicitly states the expected behavior) and also respond in a completely unhelpful manner. If this commentor is genuinely trying to explore the problem and help, they are awful at doing so.

Comment: If your goal is to say "You told the thing to print the first three characters several times." as a way to explain what the wrong piece of code does, then how in the world "What do you expect to happen?" is not condescending? You can't ask me why did I think otherwise if I could not see what my code was doing in the first place. And yes, I used "how **in the world**" and not just "how" as a way to raise awareness of the harfmful effect words can have.

Comment: To clarify: with the comment "You told the thing to print the first three characters several times." you may be explaining me why I was wrong. In this case "What do you expect to happen?" is condescending nonsense as my expectations were wrong and you could not pretend I had the right expectations. Or you are telling me what I already know as why the code did not work, and then "What do you expect to happen?" is condescendence added to condescendence.

Comment: So the full statement IS condescending. Your actors are either a malevolent condescending jerk, or a benevolent condescending line manager. I do not see any role model in this story.

Comment: @Famargar I have already clearly explained that it is completely reasonable that a person reads the phrase and all they hear is the condescending version like you are doing. That does not mean that the completely reasonable request to know what the OP was expecting the code to do sounds condescending to everyone, and it definitely does not mean that the OP was trying to be condescending. How in the world you ask? Someone has a different viewpoint than you, that's how. Someone reads it with a light friendly tone instead of that of a malevolent condescending jerk, and it becomes welcoming.

Comment: Perhaps the original author of the comment is a condescending jerk. That could be true. Just like I and others read it read it in a positive voice, perhaps a negative voice was the intention all along. That is possible. But I don't see it. And people on the internet will be a lot happier if they don't intentionally try to see or hear things with unwritten sarcasm, condescension, or otherwise offensive material that isn't there in the first place.

Comment: @DavyM I appreciate your comment that people should not expect offense - that is absolutely true. However, I tried to exhaustively explain in my second comment, why the comment "You told the thing to print the first three characters several times. What do you expect to happen?" is at best benevolently condescending. Where do you disagree with that explanation?

Comment: @DavyM Also, please note again that I used "why **in the world**" to raise awareness that a mild variation to a comment can turn a generic comment into a condescending one. That seems to have had the (un)intended effect of prompting you to explain me that people can have different viewpoint - i.e. condescendence. This is exactly how we blast each other on internet. I am proposing to be kinder to each other.

Comment: @Famargar I don't disagree that you read it as condescending, I disagree with your claim that it is absolutely at least 50% condescending. My evidence is the fact that when I read it, it doesn't sound condescending to me at all, it sounds like a genuine explanation and request. And I believe at least several of the people who upvoted my answer also don't automatically see the condescension that you are certain is there. That's why I invite people to try to read the comment in the voice of someone you know and trust not to be rude to you. But if you don't see it, don't worry. You could be -c-

Comment: right after all. Maybe the person meant to be rude and I am just being naïve. Though for me, reading everything in a positive tone makes everything feel more welcoming and keeps me happier, so I guess being naïve could just be what works for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174356/discussion-between-famargar-and-davy-m).

Answer (score 1):

The advice in the review queue, as I understand it, is to downvote *salvageable* questions.

So the downvoters indicated that the sample question isn't ready to appear on the front page yet, and the commenters advised the OP how to finish the question.

I think many new users don't see the downvote as encouragement to improve their question. Perhaps we need another way to convey that message.

Comment: Re *"downvote salvageable questions"*: Do you mean *"downvote unsalvageable questions"* (the opposite)?

Comment: No @PeterMortensen . This answer is 5 years old, and I'm not sure where I saw the advice. However the process I tried to describe is to downvote _salvageable_ questions, but if a question is the opposite, _unsalvageable_ , flag it or vote to close. I don't think voting either way on salvageable questions helps anyone, but a _down_ vote was the official guidance I had seen.