# Add a blog-post tag for Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Recently, there has been a lot of questions/discussions regarding blog posts, and it wouldn't surprise me if in the future, it kept happening.

That's why I think it would be a good idea to have a tag `blog-post` for Meta Stack Overflow.

---

A [quick search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=blog%20tag) has led me to notice that nobody has suggested this in the past.

## Update

The `blog` tag is about the blog in general:

> Questions regarding the Stack Overflow blog and other blogs in general.

The `welcoming` tag is only for one specific blog post:

> For posts about, or motivated by, Jay Hanlon's "Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming" blog.

What the `blog-post` tag would be:

> Questions regarding a post on the Stack Overflow blog

Or something similar.

## Update 2

I actually hadn't seen the tag `blog`, ironically. By the time I noticed, it was too late to delete the question.

Most questions regarding that don't even have the tag:

- *[When is Stack Overflow going to stop demonizing the quality-concerned users who have made the site a success?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366858/when-is-stack-overflow-going-to-stop-demonizing-the-quality-concerned-users-who)*
- *[Curation and cynicism: Or why Stack Overflow sometimes doesn't seem welcoming](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367016/curation-and-cynicism-or-why-stack-overflow-sometimes-doesnt-seem-welcoming)*
- *[What examples are there for Not Being Very Welcoming?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366867/what-examples-are-there-for-not-being-very-welcoming)*
- *[Bad question or example of Stack Overflow not being welcoming?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366710/bad-question-or-example-of-stack-overflow-not-being-welcoming)*

Comment: _"The blog tag is about the blog in general:"_ If you're asking about a _blog post_ then aren't you, automatically, asking about the _blog?_ I don't see how `blog` is wrong for this case.

Answer (score 5):

Posts about that blog post are tagged with [welcoming](/questions/tagged/welcoming).

There is also [blog](/questions/tagged/blog), which is basically the tag you're suggesting.

Comment: You're right, I actually hadn't noticed the `blog` tag... I updated my question.